# Cross validation and pipeline in sci-kit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

For a machine learning project, i'm trying to predict a categorical outcome variable using features extracted from text.

Using cross validation, i split my X and Y into a test set and training set. The training set is trained using a pipeline. However, when i compute the performance using X from my test set my performance is 0.0. This is while there are no features extracted from X_test yet.

Is it possible to split the dataset within the pipeline?

My code:

```
X, Y = read_data('development2.csv')

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

train_pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()), #ngram_range=(1,2), analyzer='word'
                 ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False)),
                 ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True))),
                 ])

train_pipeline.fit(X_train, Y_train)

predicted = train_pipeline.predict(X_test)

print accuracy_score(Y_test, predicted)
```

The traceback when using SVC:

```
File     "/Users/Robbert/Documents/pipeline.py", line     62, in <module>
train_pipeline.fit(X_train, Y_train)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 130, in fit
self.steps[-1][-1].fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 138, in fit
y = self._validate_targets(y)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 441, in _validate_targets
y_ = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 319, in column_or_1d
raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (670, 5)
```

Comment: What would splitting it in the pipeline accomplish? Your approach looks good to me, but you should simplify your pipeline: use a TfidfVectorizer instead of a CountVectorizer + TfidfTransformer and don't wrap your SVC in a OneVsRestClassifier. SVC can already deal with multiple classes. If the performance is not good enough, consider using other classifiers or kernels for the SVC, getting more data, using different preprocessing methods etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've changed the pipeline using TfidfVectorizer. Now i get this message: `ValueError: bad input shape (670, 5)`. A message i don't get when i use the separate functions.. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try keeping them separate then; does it help if you remove the OneVsRestClassifier?

Comment: I found out, that when i use a different classifier such as K-NN i don't get the `ValueError`. However, when i use SVC without the OneVsRestClassifier or Logistic Regression, the error returns.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? Also, I recommend against "probability=True". And if your dataset is largish,  use LinearSVC(dual=False) instead of SVC(kernel="linear").

Comment: I've added the traceback in the original post.

Comment: Y_train has the wrong size as the traceback says. Do you do multi-label prediction or multi-class prediction and what are type and shape of your original Y and Y_train?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The target variable (Y) did not have the appropriate format. The variables were stored like this: `[[0 0 0 0 1],[0 0 1 0 0]]`. I converted this to a different array format like this: `[5, 3]`.

This did the trick for me.

Thanks for all answers.